# Pandas Groupby: Warning message after performing cumsum() over different columns

Tags: pandas

I imported the following table from excel:

```
sheet5=pd.read_excel(data, 'Sheet5').set_index('item')
display(sheet5)

    x       y       days
item            
A   0.2076  0.0000  4
A   0.0000  0.0000  1
A   55.9240 39.8879 31
A   54.5062 46.2022 30
A   38.6522 32.9306 31
A   27.5890 25.7896 30
A   23.4207 21.9209 31
A   21.1067 18.6405 31
B   4.7236  4.4775  6
B   1.6416  1.1710  1
B   0.6177  0.0000  1
B   68.6652 45.7007 30
B   85.6364 61.6806 30
B   56.0095 43.1121 30
B   38.9339 25.0558 31
B   45.6508 33.9727 31
B   37.6672 32.0657 30
B   31.1604 29.2204 31
B   26.0266 24.9480 30
```

Then, I proceed to "groupby" the 'item' column and calculate a cumulative sum

```
df=sheet5.groupby(['item'])['x', 'y', 'days'].cumsum()
display(df)

    x       y       days
item            
A   0.20    0.00    4
A   0.20    0.00    5
A   56.13   39.88   36
A   110.63  86.09   66
A   149.29  119.02  97
A   176.87  144.81  127
A   200.29  166.73  158
A   221.40  185.37  189
B   4.72    4.47    6
B   6.36    5.64    7
B   6.98    5.64    8
B   75.64   51.34   38
B   161.28  113.02  68
B   217.29  156.14  98
B   256.22  181.19  129
B   301.87  215.17  160
B   339.54  247.23  190
B   370.70  276.45  221
B   396.73  301.40  251
```

I got the following warning:

```
<ipython-input-83-f4f50b80623a>:3: FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.
  df=sheet5.groupby(['item'])['x', 'y', 'days'].cumsum()
```

I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to perform this calculation and avoid getting this warning?
2. I noticed that when I don't set the item column as the index, it does not show in the result. Why would this be?
3. Is it possible to only perform the cumsum() in one column and to obtain a DataFrame with the original columns and just the result column from cumsum() from the day column?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Use `dataframe.groupby` (i.e. wrap columns in double square brackets)

```
In [848]: df.groupby('item')[['x', 'y', 'days']].cumsum()
Out[848]:
             x         y  days
item
A       0.2076    0.0000     4
A       0.2076    0.0000     5
A      56.1316   39.8879    36
A     110.6378   86.0901    66
A     149.2900  119.0207    97
A     176.8790  144.8103   127
A     200.2997  166.7312   158
A     221.4064  185.3717   189
B       4.7236    4.4775     6
B       6.3652    5.6485     7
B       6.9829    5.6485     8
B      75.6481   51.3492    38
B     161.2845  113.0298    68
B     217.2940  156.1419    98
B     256.2279  181.1977   129
B     301.8787  215.1704   160
B     339.5459  247.2361   190
B     370.7063  276.4565   221
B     396.7329  301.4045   251
```

2/ I guess `cumsum` on groupby forcing the `combine` step of the `split-apply-combine` process of groupby to use the original index like `transform`. This is just my conjecture since I don't check on the source code of `groupby.cumsum` yet.

3/ for your edited question 3, you do groupby the same on `item`, but do `cumsum` on `Series.groupby` on column `days`

```
df['days_c'] = df.groupby('item')['days'].cumsum()

Out[876]:
            x        y  days  days_c
item
A      0.2076   0.0000     4       4
A      0.0000   0.0000     1       5
A     55.9240  39.8879    31      36
A     54.5062  46.2022    30      66
A     38.6522  32.9306    31      97
A     27.5890  25.7896    30     127
A     23.4207  21.9209    31     158
A     21.1067  18.6405    31     189
B      4.7236   4.4775     6       6
B      1.6416   1.1710     1       7
B      0.6177   0.0000     1       8
B     68.6652  45.7007    30      38
B     85.6364  61.6806    30      68
B     56.0095  43.1121    30      98
B     38.9339  25.0558    31     129
B     45.6508  33.9727    31     160
B     37.6672  32.0657    30     190
B     31.1604  29.2204    31     221
B     26.0266  24.9480    30     251
```

Comment: another question if I may. Regarding my third question, is it possible to use sum() in the x and y columns and cumsum() in the days column()?

Comment: `cumsum` cumulately adds each row and retuns back the same number of rows. `sum` will reduce numbers of row for each group of `item`. What is the output you want? Could you add a desired output for question 3 to the question?

Comment: Hi @Andy L., i edited question 3. I’d like to perform the cumsum in the days column, leaving the rest as in the original dataframe. At the end, I’d like to obtain a dataframe with all the original columns plus the cumsum() one. I tried using sheet5[‘days_c’]=sheet5.groupby[‘days’].cumsum(), but i didn’t get the result i expected

Comment: @Pablo: I edited the answer for question 3. Check my updated answer

Comment: Hi @Andy L. Everything worked perfect. thank you so much!